# Excel export showing only 254 columns

Tags: excel-2007

Excel export showing only 254 columns while generating it from Birt Report tool and here we use cross tab for showing the dynamically data..Even i tried to generate the file XSL and XSLX format.

Comment: This is not an excel problem.  This needs to be fixed in Birt Report tool.

Answer (score 0):

select the data sets -->select the setting tab ---> select the fetch all rows from database check box. I hope it might be useful for you.